# How to type a parameter with multiple types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to make a class to authenticate to a web service.

```
export class MyWebService {
  constructor(settings: Settings) {}
  
  ...
}

const config: Settings = {
  apiUrl: 'https://api.domain.com',
  appToken: 'app_secret',
  userToken: 'user_secret',
};

// or 

const config: Settings = {
  apiUrl: 'https://api.domain.com',
  appToken: 'app_secret',
  auth: 'base64_encoded_basic_auth',
};

// or 

const config: Settings = {
  apiUrl: 'https://api.domain.com',
  appToken: 'app_secret',
  auth: {
    username: 'me',
    password: 'secret',
  },
};

const client = new MyWebService(config);
```

I think `Settings` should look like this but it doesn't work

```
export type AuthBasicString = string;

export type AuthBasicObject = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

export type AuthBasic = AuthBasicString | AuthBasicObject;

export type BaseSettings = {
  apiUrl: URL;
  appToken: string;
};

export type BasicAuth = BaseSettings & {
  auth: AuthBasic;
};

export type UserToken = BaseSettings & {
  userToken: string;
};

export type Settings = BasicAuth | UserToken;
```

How can I determine if the setting object is either `BasicAuth` or `UserToken` ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't work"_? And you can narrow them with e.g. `"userToken" in auth` - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing.

Comment: The only problem I see here is that you're using a string as a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), and it's not one.  But you're not asking about that, right?  What is the actual problem?  Right now this is either not a [mre] or you haven't described the issue clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can do this utilizing the 'in' operator in typescript:

```js
class MyWebService {
  constructor(config: BasicAuth | UserToken) {
    if ('userToken' in config) {
      // the config is a UserToken type
    } else {
      // the config is a BasicAuth type
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: "How can I determine if the setting object is either BasicAuth or UserToken ?"
A: With [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
function isUserToken(conf: BasicAuth | UserToken): conf is UserToken {
  return (conf as UserToken).userToken !== undefined;
}

function isBasicAuth(conf: BasicAuth | UserToken): conf is BasicAuth {
  return (conf as BasicAuth).auth !== undefined;
}

const conf: BasicAuth | UserToken = {
    apiUrl: new URL('https://api.domain.com'), 
    appToken: 'app_secret',
    auth: {
        username: 'me',
        password: 'secret',
    },
}

if (isUserToken(conf)) {
  // cons if UserToken
} else if (isBasicAuth(conf)){
  // conf is BasicAuth
}
```

and if you just say `apiUrl:'https://api.domain.com'` you will get an error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'URL'.` this is why you should use either `apiUrl:string` in type declaration or `apiUrl: new URL('https://api.domain.com')`

Comment: The thing with apiURL was just a copy/paste error. Where should I write type guards ? Now I'm wondering which is better between @Caleb Anderson's answer and your's.